# Java RMI too slow to registry.lookup in non-dev environment

Tags: java, networking, rmi

In a localhost environment, `registry.lookup` in Java RMI (Remote Method Invocation) works fine, but in production and staging environments, the same lookup takes a **very long time (ages)**, which is affecting our application's performance deeply.

We cannot find any solution, looked for other solutions here but nothing useful.

The code for the client:

```
package it.***.***.network.rmi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

/**
 * This class represents the RMI client.
 */
public class ClientRmi implements ClientRmiIF {
    private final String serverHost;
    private final int serverPort;
    private ServerRmiIF server;
    private final CommandCallback callback;
    private static Registry registry;
    public ClientRmi(String serverHost, CommandCallback callback) throws RemoteException {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", serverHost);
        this.serverHost = serverHost;
        this.serverPort = 1099;
        this.callback = callback;
        server = null;
    }

    public ClientRmi(String serverHost, int serverPort, CommandCallback callback) throws RemoteException {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", serverHost);
        this.serverHost = serverHost;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.callback = callback;
        server = null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientRmi connect() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverHost, serverPort);
        this.server = (ServerRmiIF) registry.lookup("MyRMIServer");
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the code for the server:

```
package it.***.***.network.rmi;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class represents the RMI server.
 */
public class ServerRmi implements ServerRmiIF {
    private static Registry registry;
    private final Set<ClientRmiIF> clients;
    private final CommandCallback callback;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServerRmi.class);


    public ServerRmi(String hostname, CommandCallback callback) throws RemoteException {
        clients = new HashSet<>();

        // set java.rmi.server.hostname
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", hostname);

        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            ServerRmiIF stub = (ServerRmiIF) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
            registry.rebind("MyRMIServer", stub);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        this.callback = callback;
    }
}
```

Any insights on what could be causing the difference in lookup time, or suggestions for what we can investigate, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you need to use RMI in a production application?

Comment: Uni project sadly (required)...

Comment: I can only suggest to look at the differences between production and development environments. Was development in the same machine and production communicates over the network? That could be a source of delays.

Comment: No difference, dev environment means just localhost as target ip for server